# Count closed blocks in image with opencv

Tags: python

I have an image passed to canny in OpenCv library
and the result is:

[image]

is there way to count closed black blocks in the result image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called segmentation, and uses a concept called flood-fill or region growing.

There are many methods to do this: [Watershed Algorithm](https://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html) and [Blob Detection](https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/) are two of them.